# Deploying to PROD personal domain using GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, deployment

I deployed Hello world to http://rajinination.appspot.com/ using GAE successfully. When I linked it to personal domain http://rajinination.com/ it shows a "Error 404".
I linked my personal domain to appspotdomain:
imgur.com/t8jKJ
Error 404 :
imgur.com/iwcEC

Why my personal domain shows 404 Error while appspot domain shows the code is success?

App.Yaml
 
`application: rajinination

version: 1

runtime: python27

api_version: 1

threadsafe: yes

handlers:

- url: /favicon.ico

  static_files: favicon.ico

  upload: favicon.ico

- url: .*

  script: main.app

libraries:

- name: webapp2

  version: "2.5.1"`

Main.Py
`import webapp2

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        
self.response.out.write("HelloWorld")`

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainHandler)],debug=True)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Custom Domain**

First off: to serve your app on a custom domain, you must tell Google Apps to handle requests on that domain.

See the steps over at https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/domain

This will let you serve on a subdomain, e.g. www.rajinination.com

**Naked Domain**

Then, it looks like you're trying to do a naked domain, which is an [unresolved issue with appengine](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=777) (if you read Nick's blog linked below, you'll see it's unlikely to ever be resolved).

The work-around is to have a redirect from `rajinination.com` to `www.rajinination.com`  as described in Nick's blog: http://blog.notdot.net/2009/12/Naked-domains-on-App-Engine

We're using that work-around successfully on production sites.

Comment: Thanks a lot !! :) Hello world is live now

Answer (score 2):

Here is an article from Nick Johnson about using naked domain on app engine:
http://blog.notdot.net/2009/12/Naked-domains-on-App-Engine

Comment: Thanks a lot !! :) Hello world is live now